# Autocomplete Entry in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, autocompletetextview

How to implement autocomplete Entry in Xamarin forms.

If i have an entry control and i type some text it should search the items from a set of data and display it like a drop down for the entry.

I have refereed XLabs autocomplete . But unable to implement the same properly

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/AutoComplete

Comment: Use [SyncFusion AutoComplete](http://syncfusion.com/products/xamarin/autocomplete) control. And also [Community Licence](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) available.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using the following components.

1. An Entry field with TextChanged Event.
2. A ListView which to display the data set.

As a first step you can create the Entry and ListView in a StackLayout with Vertical alignment. Set ItemSource of the ListView to your data set.
Add the following code in your function for TextChanged event

```
    void OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Site_listView.ItemsSource = vm.SiteList.Where(x => x.siteName.ToLower().Contains(siteNameEntry.Text.ToString().ToLower())).ToList();

    }
```

Site_listView, siteNameEntry are the x:Name of ListView and Entry respectively

You can use ItemSelected/ItemTapped events in the list view for selecting the item from the list and assigning it to the Entry. Also you can use Focused, UnFocused events also to set the visibility of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `TextChanged` Property. That's an event. It will fire every time when you will Enter the text in the entry.

**EX:**
**XAML code:**

```
<Entry x:Name="searchCustomer" Placeholder="Search Customer" TextChanged ="searchCustomerList" Completed="searchCustomerList"></Entry>
```

**CS code:**

```
 protected void searchCustomerList(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
 {
  var searchText = searchCustomer.Text;
   if (searchText != null)
     {
        var FilterSearchCustomer =vendorCustomerList.Where(x => x.FirstName.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())).ToList();
     }
 }
```